# Python time complexity convert O(n^2) code to O(n)

Tags: python, algorithm, recursion

> The recursive function dumbo_func, which has been preloaded into the answer box, has O(n^2) performance. Rewrite it (still using recursion) so that its performance becomes O(n). Your function will be tested in a loop calling it 20 times with a list of up to 10,000 elements and will time out if the function is still O(n^2 ).
>
> Note that the function is preceded by code to increase the maximum
> recursion depth. You will need to include that code when doing your
> own testing and when submitting your answer. However, under Microsoft
> Windows you'll probably crash the Python interpreter if you try lists
> of more than about 2000 elements. On a lab machine or on the quiz
> server, a list size of 10,000 will be fine, provided you've made the
> necessary change to the code so it's O(n) rather than O(n2).

```
import sys
sys.setrecursionlimit(100000)

def dumbo_func(data):
    """Takes a list of numbers and does weird stuff with it"""
    if len(data) == 0:
        return 0
    else:
        if (data[0] // 100) % 3 != 0:
            return 1 + dumbo_func(data[1:])
        else:
            return dumbo_func(data[1:])

#Test1
#Simple test with short list.
#Original func works fine on this
#Result: 3
data = [677, 90, 785, 875, 7, 90393, 10707]  
print(dumbo_func(data)) 


#Test2
#This test will timeout with a O(n^2) function
#Result: Yay!
ok = True
for i in range(20):
    # Repeat enough times to ensure timeout on O(n^2)
    data = list(range(10_000))
    right_ans = secret_version(data)
    your_ans = dumbo_func(data)
    if your_ans != right_ans:
        print("Sorry, but no banana")
        ok = False
        break
if ok:
    print("Yay!")
```

> I wrote my code as below which pass test1 but doesn't pass test2. Isn't my code O(n)? Please advise where inappropriate.

```
import sys
sys.setrecursionlimit(100000)

def dumbo_func(data):
    """Takes a list of numbers and does weird stuff with it"""
    if len(data) == 0:
        return 0
    else:
        return int((data[0] // 100) % 3 != 0) + dumbo_func(data[1:])
```

Comment: You can test the runtime of your code yourself by running it on large examples. For example [0]*10000.

Comment: Every recursive call is copying the entire passed-in list (less one element).  This takes time and will likely overflow your stack on large lists, even before recursion limit is reached.

Answer (score 3):

[Here's](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-list-slicing/) a simple guide on list slicing. Long story short, the recursive function is `O(N^2)` because slicing the list each time to call the function recursively takes `O(N)` time per each slice.

Solution: try sending the index of the first element of the subarray you're considering to the recursive function, rather then sending the entire sliced array as an argument.

Hint: `def func(data, index_of_first_element)` rather than `def func(data)`

Comment: I tried sending the index to the subarray but the time limit exceed for [0]*10000

Answer (score 0):

> I tried sending the index to the subarray but the time limit exceed for [0]*10000

```
import sys
sys.setrecursionlimit(100000)

def dumbo_func(data, start_index=0):
    """Takes a list of numbers and does weird stuff with it"""
    if len(data) - start_index == 0:
        return 0
    else:
        if (data[start_index] // 100) % 3 != 0:
            return 1 + dumbo_func(data, start_index+1)
        else:
            return dumbo_func(data, start_index+1)

data = [677, 90, 785, 875, 7, 90393, 10707]
print(dumbo_func(data))
data = [0]*10000 
print(dumbo_func(data))
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: I executed this in an online IDE, changed the number of iterations to 40 instead of 20, and it worked fine without any timeout